# How to give a value to a placeholder who is in a constant?

Tags: c#, constants, placeholder

I have a constant which returns a text for an exception. In this constant I have a placeholder which I have to use. How am I supposed to use this placeholder?

Here is my code:

```
public static class Messages
{
    public const string ShipDestroyed = "{0} has been destroyed";
}
```

I use the constant in this method in another class:

```
protected void ValidateAlive(IStarship ship)
{
    if (ship.Health <= 0)
    {
        throw new ShipException(Messages.ShipDestroyed); 
    }
}
```

I want to put the "ship.Name" property into the placeholder.

Comment: It is always good idea to check your course notes - frequently homework assignments refer to recent topics (which probably "string formatting in C#").

Answer (score 10):

Use [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting):

```
throw new ShipException(String.Format(Messages.ShipDestroyed, ship.Name));
```

If you follow the link, you can see what kind of nice stuff you can do with it.